# Trigger resp api on kafka event

Tags: java, apache-kafka, wso2, kafka-consumer-api

we are creating some kind of a business process pipeline using wso2 and kafka. Do you know if it's possible to trigger some rest API on kafka event?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using WSO2 Stream Processor 4.2[1][2] find its docs [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP420/Stream+Processor+Documentation)

Use its [Kafka source](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-kafka/api/latest/#kafka-source) to consume the events from Kafka and use its [Http sink](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-http/api/latest/) to call the endpoint.

[1]https://wso2.com/analytics

[2]https://github.com/wso2/product-sp/releases